# pretty print java with no xml conversion

Tags: java, xml, pretty-print

**I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times on this site, however none of the previous answers have worked for me.**

I have a String as XML like `<A><B/><C></C></A>`

When I use the pretty print converters I get:

`<A>
  <B/>
  <C/>
</A>`

I want to stop this and get the XML as it was. Like:

`<A>
  <B/>
  <C></C>
</A>`

I want an indent=2. Kindly help.

Comment: According to the XML standard, both `<B/>` and `<B></B>` are equivalent. They meant the same thing, so you should be all good.

Comment: I wish the requirement would have been simpler. My testers are over my head to fix this. They will not understand the specification. :-)

Comment: So they want pretty-print, but not pretty-print. Good luck with that :( -- To clarify, I mean pretty-print requires parsing, which requires interpreting the semantics and outputting a different form. And due to the equivalence of the 2 forms stated above, I'm afraid that info is lost by most parser/pretty-printers...

Comment: Then your tester should fix his/her test results.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment section, for empty XML element tag both

```
<B></B>
```

and

```
<B/>
```

are equivalent.

I think you should try negotiate with your tester to save you the trouble as this sort of "fix" is deem as unnecessary. I would say your XML code is working as expected.

Try pointing your tester to the W3C XML specification.

**See:**
https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EmptyElemTag

**Quote from the link above:**

Examples of empty elements:

```
<IMG align="left"
 src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/WWW/w3c_home" />
<br></br>
<br/>
```